# how to grep unique duplicate records on base of column with count in solaris

Tags: sorting, grep, uniq, solaris-10

I want to `grep` logs for exceptions and identify unique with their counts

Following is sample input

```
[msisdn:123][trxId:1234] | subscriptions | java.lang.Exception: this msidn NOT found
[msisdn:432][trxId:1212] | subscriptions | java.lang.Exception: this msidn NOT found
[msisdn:232][trxId:3232] | subscriptions | java.lang.Exception: this msidn NOT found
```

I used following and it shows duplicate with count

```
grep -i exception my.log| cut -d'|' -f2- | uniq –c
```

its shows results as expected, but i loose first part which contain msisdn and trxid, then i used following

```
grep -i exception my.log | sort -u  -k 2,3 -t'|'
```

it shows unique results with sample line and on base of that sample line which contained *msisdn* and *trxid* I can troubleshoot.

Now how I can get count with my last command used?

Comment: Edit your question to show the expected output given that sample input, I have no idea if you're trying to find the count per msisdn or per trxid or per combination of both or something else. Whatever it is will be absolutely trivial with one small, clear awk script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
grep -i exception my.log | sort -k 2,3 -t'|' | uniq -c -f 1
```

Output:

```
      3 [msisdn:123][trxId:1234] | subscriptions | java.lang.Exception: this msidn NOT found
```